# Security concerns with cache_get() and cache_set()

Tags: 7, ajax, caching, security

are there any security concerns with Drupal's cache_set() and cache_get() functions?
I mean, I receive some values through an Ajax-GET-request. Can I pass them to the two functions with the following validation?

Javascript:

```
//token was passed through drupal_add_js() to Drupal.settings.my_module
var url = path + token + '/' + var1 + '/' + var2;
$.get(url);
```

Page callback:

```
function my_module_ajax_callback($token, $var1, $var2) {  
  if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
      && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'
      && is_numeric($var1)
      && drupal_valid_token($token, $var1)) {

    if (is_numeric($var2) && $var2 >= 0 && $var2 < 3600) {
      //can I pass $var1 and $var2 to cache_get() and cache_set() at this point? e.g.:
      cache_set(var1, var2);
      //Are there still security risks?
    }
  }
}
```

I would welcome every advise.

Thanks!

Daniel

Comment: Most of the security in Drupal is achieved through menu router access, form CSRF, and output sanitizing. Make sure you handle the data properly after cache_get(_multiple) calls.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! But there cannot happen some SQL injection with cache_get and cache_set? It is as save as Drupal's db functions (e.g. db_query)?

Comment: If the cache is in the DB then yes @user3083978. Everything DB-related in Drupal runs through PDO with prepared statements. If you're using a 3rd party cache plugin you'll need to consult its code and make sure you're happy with how it sanitises input in whatever context that might be. And as Ayesh notes, always sanitise when you're outputting those vars

Comment: Thanks Clive for your fast response. I pass these vars to $form_state of a multi step form, but I think that this won't cause some of the security risks mentioned by Ayesh, right?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking - what specific security concern are you trying to deal with?

Comment: You said, that I should always sanitise when I output the vars. But I don't output the vars directly to the user as part of the HTML DOM. I pass them to a form with $form_state. Is it also necessary to sanitise them in this case? I'm not talking about a specific security concern, I ask for a general use case: Should I sanitise data (received from the user) when I pass them to $form_state?

Comment: Security is a huge topic and there is no single solution to make things secure. Always, always sanitize the user input whenever necessary. 
Cache tables, if you are using default cache, stores the values in the DB. Drupal uses PDO so as long as you use the API correctly, your module should be safe from SQL injections.

Comment: If you are trying to do something related to Ajax, consider using Drupal's Ajax framework. It handles form building and handling for you. There was an excellent article written by rfay but I couldn't find it yet.

Comment: Yes thanks. The Ajax-GET-Request, which I mentioned in my question, is just a shortened example. But I use it to call an ajaxified multi step form. And this form is completely build with the Ajax framework. After each step I need to do some calculations with var1 and var2, so I passed them to $form_state.
You said, that I should always sanitize any kind of output. Ok, I checked [link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/group/sanitization/7), but I'm not sure which function I should use, because I already checked, if the vars are just numeric.

Comment: @user3083978 It's up to you - if the input you're provided is _not_ an integer, do you consider that a security risk in the context of your application? If so, ensure it's an integer and you'll be done. SQL injection is handled for you if you use the API, and XSS is not an issue if you're not rendering the value as part of any response. But it might be if you plan to use it in, say, an HTML email. There isn't an answer to your question other than "it depends what you want to do with the data"

Comment: Clive and Ayesh, thanks for your fast and qualified support. The values won't be rendered, they are just for calculation. Therefore I will ensure that they are integers and I should be on the save side. Thanks! Do you want to post one of your comments as an answer, so that I can mark them as best solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently there are no known  bugs which would cause any security issue using cache_set and cache_get. You can put any values there
both key and value are escaped. 
for example you can try this key `'; drop table abr;--'`
and it will be saved without any issues